# How is this exam question about confidence intervals supposed to be interpreted?

Tags: confidence-interval

1. I was told to simulate a distribution $X$ which is standard normal.
2. I was then told to estimate the mean. I did so via $\hat{\mu} = \frac{1}{n}\sum x_i$.
3. I was then asked to generate an asymptotic confidence interval for $\hat{\mu}$.

How do you interpret this last question?

First of all, it confuses me that they want a confidence interval for $\hat{\mu}$ rather than $\mu$ itself.

Also, when generating the confidence interval, when do I use my estimates of $\mu$ and $\sigma$, and when do I use the real $\mu$ and $\sigma$ (which are 0 and 1)?

How would **you** answer this question?

Comment: Welcome to our site.  Question 3 is indeed nonsense, but you can make sense of it by replacing "$\hat \mu$" by "$\mu.$"  If you know $\mu,$ then what sense would it make to compute any kind of confidence interval for it?

Comment: If we take Question 3 literally, would the answer then be something like: $1 \pm 1.96/\sqrt{n}$?. Is that not an interval in which our estimator would lie 95 % of the time if we simulated many new processes and got new estimators from them?

Comment: Probably not, because (by definition) the confidence interval depends on the data; the data are random; and therefore the endpoints of the interval will also be random values that almost always change from one run of your simulation to another.

Comment: "Confidence interval depends on the data". Do they? In my case, $\hat{\mu}$ is a function of $X_1, ..., X_N$, so it is also a random variable. Does it not make sense to ask questions such as finding bounds so that $P(\text{lower} \le \hat{\mu} \le \text{upper}) = 0.95$?. Maybe this is what Question 3 is asking for?

Comment: Before you challenge standard statistical theory, please take a look at some of our better posts on confidence intervals: https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=%22confidence%20interval%22.

Comment: You're correct in querying Q3, but it's likely a simple typographical error. If we simply assume that an interval for $\mu$ is required there's no need to get tied up in knots.

Answer (score 1):

I like this question a lot, and use similar ones. The setup of the question is such that you pretend that you don't know population mean and variance. You obtain their estimates from generated samples, then look at the distribution of the estimates. For instance, you can draw a histogram of sample mean estimates. This teach you the concept of the sample mean, and its difference from population mean.
It also teaches you the basics of bootstrapping and simulation usage in inferential statistics.

Once you get the empirical distribution of the sample mean, you can get its percentiles. The percentiles help you estimate the confidence interval. Alternatively, you could fit some distribution into the sample means, and do the confidence intervals parametrically.

Comment: So what sort of confidence interval would you expect when asking Question 3? That is still not entirely clear to me. Do you want a confidence interval around the true mean or the sample mean?

Comment: By definition, "confidence interval around the sample mean" makes no sense.  You already *have* the sample mean--it is whatever it is and needs no interval.  Regardless, *based on the data* you still do not know the true mean: thus, in many applications your assertions about it can benefit from providing some quantitative assessment of how well you think you know it.  That's the purpose of a confidence interval.

Comment: Do you know the true mean in the context of your question? Think of this: when do you really know the true mean? Also, you need to add a self-study tag and read its instructions. You're asking an answer to assignment - that's not how it works here